# Recompiling Ubuntu kernel 12.04 on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have to recompile the Ubuntu 12.04 kernel for 1000Hz and I am following the documentation available [here](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Amazon_EC2#Updating_Kernel_Timer_to_1000HZ) but its for Lucid and has a specific ec2 branch. Is is possible to recompile the precise kernel for EC2? If not, can I use the Lucid kernel?

Comment: What do you mean by recompiling for 1000hz? What is this measurement for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the right way to do this for Precise on EC2 is to use the low-latency kernel available from apt repo.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me, using existing "Ubuntu-3.2.0-32.51" branch (i.e git checkout Ubuntu-3.2.0-32.51 -b ec2-asterisk)

P.S
It has booted into the newly compiled kernel([with 1000Hz ticking](http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php)) but I haven't thoroughly tested it...